# tornado AsyncHTTPClient.fetch exception

Tags: python, exception, tornado

I am using `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.fetch` to fetch domains from list. When I put domains to fetch with some big interval(500 for example) all works good, but when I decrease the inerval to 100, next exception occurs time to time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/crchemist/python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/simple_httpclient.py", line 289, in cleanup
    yield
  File "/home/crchemist/python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 183, in wrapped
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crchemist/python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/simple_httpclient.py", line 384, in _on_chunk_length
    self._on_chunk_data)
  File "/home/crchemist/python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 180, in read_bytes
    self._check_closed()
  File "/home/crchemist/python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 504, in _check_closed
    raise IOError("Stream is closed")
IOError: Stream is closed
```

What can be the reason of this behavior? Code looks like this:

```
def fetch_domain(domain):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    request = HTTPRequest('http://' + domain,
       user_agent=CRAWLER_USER_AGENT)
    http_client.fetch(request, handle_domain)


class DomainFetcher(object):
    def __init__(self, domains_iterator):
        self.domains = domains_iterator

    def __call__(self):
        try:
            domain = next(self.domains)
        except StopIteration:
            domain_generator.stop()
            ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
        else:
            fetch_domain(domain)

domain_generator = ioloop.PeriodicCallback(DomainFetcher(domains), 500)
domain_generator.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that `tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback` [takes a cycle time **in integer ms**](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/_modules/tornado/ioloop.html#PeriodicCallback) while the [`HTTPRequest`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/_modules/tornado/httpclient.html#HTTPRequest) object is configured with a `connect_timeout` and/or a `request_timeout` of float **seconds** ([see doc](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html)).

"*Users browsing the Internet feel that responses are "instant" when delays are less than 100 ms from click to response*" ([from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_performance#Relationship_between_latency_and_throughput)) See [this ServerFault question for **normal latency** values](https://serverfault.com/questions/137348/how-much-network-latency-is-typical-for-east-west-coast-usa).

`IOError: Stream is closed` is validly being raised to inform you that your connection timed out without completing, or more accurately, you called the callback manually on a pipe that wasn't open yet. This is good, since it is not abnormal for latency to be > 100ms; if you expect your fetches to complete reliably you should raise this value.

Once you've got your timeout set to something sane, consider wrapping your fetches in a try/except retry loop as this is a normal exception *that you can expect to occur in production*. Just be careful to set a retry limit!

---

Since you're using an async framework, why not let it handle the async callback itself instead of running said callback on a fixed interval? [Epoll/kqueue are efficient and supported by this framework.](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html?highlight=epoll%20kqueue)

```
import ioloop

def handle_request(response):
    if response.error:
        print "Error:", response.error
    else:
        print response.body
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", handle_request)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

^ Copied verbatim [from the doc](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html).

If you go this route, the only gotcha is to code your request queue so that you have a maximum open connections enforced. Otherwise you're likely to end up with a race condition when doing serious scraping.

It's been ~1yr since I touched Tornado myself, so please let me know if there are inaccuracies in this response and I will revise.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are writing something like web crawler. You problem is cause by timeout directly, but in deep, related to the parallel pattern in tornado.

Of course, `AsyncHTTPClient` in tornado could automatically queue the requests. Actually, `AsyncHTTPClient` will send 10 requests(by default) in batch, and block to wait for their result, then send the next batch. The requests within batch is non-block and process in parallel, but it is block between batches. And the callback for each request is not called immediately after that request has done, but after that batch of requests has done and then call 10 callbacks.

Back to your problem, you needn't to use `ioloop.PeriodicCallback` to incrementally make the requests, since `AsyncHTTPClient` in tornado could automatically queue the requests. You could assign all of the requests in one time, let the `AsyncHTTPClient` to schedule the requests.

But here comes the problem that **requests in the waiting queue still consume the timeout time**! Because **requests are block between batches**. Later requests are simply block here, and send batch by batch, rather than put them in a special ready queue and send a new requests once a response arrived.

Therefore, the default timeout set to 20s is too-short if many requests scheduled. If you are just making a demo, you could directly set the timeout to `float('inf')`. If making something serious, you have to use try/except retry loop.

You could find how to set timeout from [`tornado/httpclient.py`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/httpclient.py), quote here.

> `connect_timeout`: Timeout for initial connection in seconds
>   `request_timeout`: Timeout for entire request in seconds

In the end, I write a simple program that use `AsyncHTTPClient` to fetch thousands of pages from ZJU Online Judgement System. You could have a try on this, and then rewrite to your crawler. On my network, it could fetch 2800 pages in 2 minutes. Very good results, 10 times(exactly match the parallel size) faster than serial fetch.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient, HTTPRequest
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

baseUrl = 'http://acm.zju.edu.cn/onlinejudge/showProblem.do?problemCode='

start = 1001
end = 3800
count = end - start
done = 0

client = AsyncHTTPClient()

def onResponse(response):
    if response.error:
        print('Error: %s' % response.error)
    else:
        global done
        done += 1
        #It is comment out here, you could uncomment it and watch something interest, that len(client.queue) is reduce 10 by 10.
        #print('Queue length %s, Active client count %s, Max active clients limit %s' % (len(client.queue), len(client.active), client.max_clients))
        print('Received %s, Content length %s, Done %s' % (response.effective_url[-4:], len(response.body), done))
        if(done == count):
            IOLoop.instance().stop()

for i in range (start, end):
    request = HTTPRequest(baseUrl + str(i), connect_timeout=float('inf'), request_timeout=float('inf'))
    client.fetch(request, onResponse)
    print('Generated %s' % i)

IOLoop.instance().start()
```

#### Extra:

If you have plenty of pages to fetch, and you are the type of people that chase for best performance, you could have a look on `Twisted`. I write a same program with `Twisted` and paste it on my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Preffer/4bdef9a3eaf640ae429f). Its result is awesome: fetch 2800 pages in 40 seconds.